# Sum(Sum()) in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can please any one help me to sort this error. I have a query of sum of sum, while executing the query i have an error shown below.

```
select distinct
    t1.whscode,
    'Invoice',
    count(distinct t1.DocEntry),
    sum(
        case when t0.DiscPrcnt>0 and t0.DpmAmnt>0 then
            (sum(t1.LineTotal)-t0.DiscPrcnt)-t0.DpmAmnt
        else 
            (sum(t1.LineTotal)-t0.DpmAmnt)
        end
    )
from 
    oinv t0 (NOLOCK) 
    inner join inv1 t1 (NOLOCK)
        on t0.docentry=t1.docentry 
where 
    t0.DocDate between '10-25-16' and '10-25-16'
    and t1.whscode='tamst' 
group by
    t1.whscode
```

**Error**:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: If you take a step back from "SQL Server refuses to run my query" to "What I want to accomplish", could you explain the reasoning behind this? There's only ever going to be 1 group in play from an aggregate standpoint that SUM looks at so "SUM(SUM(..." really makes no sense. Perhaps all you want to do is remove the SUM(...) from inside the case expression?

Comment: Note the `distinct` is not required when already grouping records.

Comment: Slightly off topic but you should read this article before you continue littering your queries with NOLOCK hints. It is far more sinister than most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OVER` as the below:

```
SELECT
    A.whscode,
    'Invoice',
    COUNT(distinct A.DocEntry),
    SUM(case when A.DiscPrcnt > 0 and A.DpmAmnt > 0 then (A.LineTotal - A.DiscPrcnt)-A.DpmAmnt else (A.LineTotal-A.DpmAmnt) end)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t1.whscode,
        t1.DocEntry,
        t0.DiscPrcnt,
        t0.DpmAmnt,
        sum(t1.LineTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.whscode) LineTotal
    from oinv t0 (NOLOCK) inner join inv1 t1 (NOLOCK) on t0.docentry=t1.docentry 
    where t0.DocDate between '10-25-16' and '10-25-16' and t1.whscode='tamst' 
) A
GROUP BY
    A.whscode
```